# Chart.js + React: How to create a custom label with amount and percentage

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

I'm using React, TypeScript and react-chartjs-2. I need to create a custom label for my pie chart that shows the label name, amount of data and percentage. I want it to look like this:

Orange
10 / 50%

Banana
5 / 25%

Strawberry
5 / 25%

So that the label name is on the first row and the amount and percentage on the second. And the label color would be next to it. Currently my code only shows the label name and color, and I don't know how to add the amount and percentage to it.

This is what I have right now:

```
  const [data, setData] = useState<ChartData<'pie'>>();
  const [options, setOptions] = useState<ChartOptions<'pie'>>();

// Data for the pie chart (comes from a form)
const foods = [
    { value: field1, label: 'Orange' },
    { value: field2, label: 'Banana' },
    { value: field3, label: 'Strawberry' },
  ];

  // Pie chart code here
  function PieData() {
    setData({
        labels: foods.map(food => food.label),
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Foods',
            data: foods.map(food => food.value),
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            ],
            borderWidth: 1,
          },
        ],
    })
    setOptions({
      responsive: true,
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          position: 'right',
          rtl : true,
          labels: {
            usePointStyle: true,
            pointStyle: 'circle',
          }
        },
      },
    });
  }
```

And here I return the pie chart:

```
<Pie id="pieChart" data={data} options={options}/>
```

So I assume that I have to edit the options, but I don't really know how.

Comment: Do you want to add the percentage to the "legend" item or to the data set one?

Comment: To the legend one

Answer (score 0):

You should use generatedlabels options.

Here is the legend config to use:

```
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      position: 'right',
      rtl : true,
      labels: {
        usePointStyle: true,
        pointStyle: 'circle',
        generateLabels(chart) {
          const dataset = chart.data.datasets[0];
          const meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(0);
          const total = meta.total;
          const legendItems = Chart.controllers.doughnut.overrides.plugins.legend.labels.generateLabels(chart);
          for (const item of legendItems) {
            const value = dataset.data[item.index];
            const percentage = value / total * 100
            item.text = item.text + ': ' + value + ' / ' + percentage.toFixed(0) + '%';
          }
          return legendItems;
        }
      }
    },
  },
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I don't get this to work. I'm getting errors for total, Chart and value.

Comment: For this one: const total = meta.total, 

I get an error: 

Property 'total' does not exist on type 'ChartMeta<keyof ChartTypeRegistry, Element<AnyObject, AnyObject>, Element<AnyObject, AnyObject>>'.
  Property 'total' does not exist on type '_DeepPartialObject<{}> & ChartMetaCommon<Element<AnyObject, AnyObject>, Element<AnyObject, AnyObject>>'.ts(2339)

Comment: And for this: const legendItems = Chart.controllers.doughnut.overrides.plugins.legend.labels.generateLabels(chart), I get: Cannot find name 'Chart'. Did you mean 'chart'?ts(2552)

Comment: And for this:  const percentage = value / total * 100, I get: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.ts(2362)
'value' is possibly 'null'.ts(18047)

Comment: Do I have to import something? I have these now: 
`import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  ArcElement,
  Title
} from 'chart.js';`

`import { Pie } from 'react-chartjs-2';`
`import type { ChartData, ChartOptions } from 'chart.js';`

`ChartJS.register(
  ArcElement,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  Title
);`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Piechart and here is what I did. You can override the label on chart options as follows:

```
  const options: ChartOptions<'doughnut'> = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          label: (d) => {
            const percentage = ` ${+d.raw * 100}%`

            return percentage
          },
        },
      },
    },
  }
```